exe created by pyinstaller cannot run
I have been trying to use pyinstaller to create an exe that can be run on any computer for sharing my program. My program uses JSON files to store past scores, settings, etc. For some reason, the exe produced by pyinstaller crashes.
PyInstaller has worked before without JSON files with (very) simple scripts (things like hello world programs to test that it works), so I believe this error occurs because:

it can't find the JSON files
it can't find the modules I imported (time, os, random, json, and sys)
it can't find either!

I have not imported any other modules aside from the ones mentioned above
I have tried the following:

putting the json files into a data folder as well as in the source directory
using pyinstaller without --onefile
using --add-data data:./data
using --add-data data/past_scores.json:./data/past_scores.json ...

as I have tried the above, it might be that some or all of the modules were not included in the exe and could not be found. The other option is that I included the json files wrong. Or maybe both.
edit: after reading the message of the error produced when running the exe using terminal, it output this error:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/topics.json'
this means that the program cannot find the json files. once I moved the data folder from _include to the source directory of the exe, it runs!
however, when I use --onefile, the program only seems to run when I copy the data folder to the source directory of the exe.
is it possible to bundle the files with the exe so that it is not neccesary to have them both together, or is this just a limitation of pyinstaller? the json files contain data i don't want the user to be able to view or modify (e.g. high scores, correct answers)

Static JSON data can be represented as a dict or list in Python. If you want to embed static data (i.e. answers) into the program then why do you need the files? Why not write the data as a Python data structure? If you want to persist dynamic data (such as high scores) then, if the file doesn't exist, catch the exception and create the file.

@MT0 i put it all in a JSON file so that it’s easier for me to add questions and also so that my python code doesn’t become a giant wall of text (esp. since i have like over a hundred topics each with up to 10 questions)

i simply want to ask whether it is possible to bundle data, such as images and JSON files, using pyinstaller, to prevent it from being viewed or modified, or if that is not possible

@MT0 i am using —add-data to add the files but the exe only runs when i copy the data folder to the same directory as the python file. i would like to know whether this is a limitation of pyinstaller or if it is possible to include the files in the exe.

This is not an effective way to prevent sophisticated users from viewing and modifying files. Anyone who knows what they're doing can unpack the executable pyinstaller created, modify the files therein, and create a new archive with those updated files. (Decompilation tools for Python are running behind bytecode changes, so folks you gave the exe to won't necessarily be able to change the code itself, but data files are much easier; and someone willing to work at the bytecode level can change the code too -- it's not impossible, it's just more work).

Anyhow -- pyinstaller creates a zip-like archive inside the generated exe, and arbitrary files can absolutely be included in that archive.
